# Making an android wear app with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

`final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.WatchViewStub);`

```
Error: Unexpected cast to WatchViewStub: layout tag was RelativeLayout
```

What does this mean? This code is inside the file from the get-go so I don't understand why it isn't working. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: please show your XML code

Comment: It is obvious that findViewById found RelativeLayout with same Id first, So the problem is in your layout. try https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchViewStub sample from google as reference